# Regex en Java: buscar número entre caracteres

Tags: java, regex

Estoy haciendo un programa en el que en cierto momento se le pide al usuario que ingrese un número. Este número servirá para buscar información en un archivo de texto, que luce de la siguiente forma:

```
texto no importante...

C   >>  71,81,91,
L   >>  72,82,92,
M   >>  72,83,93,
F   >>  71,81,92,
W   >>  71,81,91,

más texto sin importancia...
```

De todo ese texto, necesito extraer información de esas líneas en específico.

La información que necesito rescatar de este archivo de texto será el número siguiente a la entrada numérica del usuario; es decir, si el usuario ingresa un 7 debo extraer un 1 (el que está entre el 7 y la coma en la línea que empieza con `C >>`), un 2 (el que está entre el 7 y la coma en la línea que empieza con `L >>`) y así sucesivamente. Si el input numérico del usuario es un 8, buscaré todos los números que haya entre los 8 y las comas en esas cinco líneas que importan. Lo mismo si el input es un 9.

Para esto, abro y recorro el archivo en mi programa Java de la forma:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("nombreDelArchivo.txt"))) {
    // Lectura del archivo...
}
```

Una vez abierto el archivo, lo recorro línea por línea con un bucle de la forma:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   // Búsqueda...
}
```

Dentro de este bucle, trato primero de buscar las líneas importantes y luego buscar la información dentro de estas líneas. Para ello, primero me fijo si la línea que está siendo leída matchea con la siguiente expresión regular:

`[CLMFW].>`

Es decir, que se tope con una línea que comience con C, L, M, F ó W, seguido de lo que sea (en este caso tabs) y luego una cuña (`>`).

Cuando la línea matchea con esta regex, significa que estoy leyendo una línea que me interesa, por lo que ahora debo buscar la información que me importa dentro de esta línea. Para esto, investigué mucho sobre cómo hacer una regex que matchee **todo excepto una secuencia de caracteres**, y en particular [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37988661/12980444) me ayudó bastante.

No soy un experto en expresiones regulares ni mucho menos, aún me queda bastante por aprender, pero la regex que me pareció interesante en aquella respuesta fue la siguiente:

`/cat(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?:(?!cat).)+/is`

En aquella respuesta se indica que esta regex busca todo lo que no sea `cat`. Es un poco compleja para mí, realmente. Estuve buscando sobre el *negative lookahead* pero aún no termino de comprender cómo funciona tal expresión regular.

El caso es que simplemente experimentando en las páginas [regexr](https://regexr.com/) y [regex101](https://regex101.com/) pude obtener algunos resultados.

Como esperaba, la primera expresión regular (`[CLMFW].>`) [matchea correctamente](https://regexr.com/5ou83).

Para la segunda expresión regular, intenté modificarla y jugar un poco con algunas cosas y terminé con la siguiente regex funcional:

`(SKIP)(FAIL)|(?:(?!(?<=7)(.*)(?=,)).)+`

En teoría, estaría buscando los caracteres que estén entre el número 7 y la coma en cada línea. Cargué nuevamente el archivo en la página junto con la regex y esta [también matchea correctamente](https://regexr.com/5ou86).

Estoy buscando las cosas de esta manera para poder reemplazar en aquellas líneas específicas todo aquello que no sean los números que me importen por una cadena vacía (`""`) dado el input del usuario.

El código en Java que hice para corroborar que esto ande bien es el siguiente:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("archivo.txt"))) {
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        if (line.matches("[CLMFW].>")) {
            line.replaceAll("(SKIP)(FAIL)|(?:(?!(?<=7)(.*)(?=,)).)+", "");
            System.out.println(line);
        }
}
```

El problema es que si bien en las páginas que uso para corroborar las regex andan bien, el método `replaceAll(regex, replace)` pareciera que no encuentra ningún match porque nada se reemplaza. Es altamente probable que esté equivocándome en la segunda expresión regular pero aún no logro entender del todo por qué.

Estoy trabado en esto hace tiempo y me gustaría poder solucionarlo. Cualquier ayuda es útil.

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Cuidado! `[CLMFW].>` no tiene un *match* completo de la linea.

No es igual: `C  >` a `C  >>  71,91,81,` (*linea entera*)

Por esa razón no cumple esa validación, algo un poco diferente es, por ejemplo:
`[CLMFW].+>.+` un punto `.` para cualquier carácter y el *mas* `+` para encontrar tantos cuantos haya por ahi; con eso ya se cubre el 100% de la cadena que llega del archivo;  sirve `line.matches("[CLMFW].+>.+")`

Eso por un lado, ahora la otra *regex* que utilizas en el `replaceAll`; con algo de ensayo y error probé `\\D+\\d|[^\\d]` de tal modo que se excluyen:

- `\\D+\\d`   (un digito que esté precedido de cualquier caracter no dígito: `C   >>  1,1,1`)
- `[^\\d]` (todo caracter que NO sea numérico: `111`)

termina dejando ese `111` (*valores de 7 8 y 9*), solo por dar un panorama de todo ésto me antojé de trabajarlo haciendo `split`:

```
System.out.print("Input: "+num+" -> ");
while((line=BR.readLine())!=null) {
  if(line.matches("[CLMFW].+>.+")) {
    switch(num) {
      case 7: index=1;
      break;
      case 8: index=2;
      break;
      case 9: index=3;
      break;
    }
    val=Integer.parseInt(line.split("\\D+\\d|[^\\d]")[index]);
    System.out.print(val+" ");
  }
}
```

Teniendo en el archivo:

```
texto no importante...

C   >>  721,81,91003,
L   >>  72,82,92,
M   >>  72,83501,93,
F   >>  7132,81,990210,
W   >>  71,81,91,

más texto sin importancia...
```

Output:

```
Input: 7 -> 21 2 2 132 1
Input: 8 -> 1 2 3501 1 1
Input: 9 -> 1003 2 3 90210 1
```

Seguramente hay una manera mas eficiente de diferenciar el numero ingresado pero me parece ésta una buena aproximación.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias, @JohnnyTB! Los ejemplos que utilizaste me han ayudado bastante, voy a poner en práctica lo que me has aportado y evaluaré los resultados. ¡Muchas gracias nuevamente!